# How can I break the retain cycles in my code?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

Recently I was dropped into someone else's codebase I've been able to tackle most things it's thrown up so far but this one is a little over my head. There's some retain cycles that I can't figure out how to fix.

There is a custom object that wraps an FROAuthRequest, the FROAuthRequest has a completion block in which there are a further 3 blocks used, a parsing, finish and fail blocks. The completion, finish and fail blocks are all causing a retain cycle.

I know that the cause is references to ivars within the block but what I've tried hasn't worked, see the end of the post for what I tried.

The following code is as it was before I started trying to fix it.The code path goes as follows:

1: Create the request:

```
//in the MainViewController.m
SHRequest *request = [api userInfo];
```

2: The method that creates the SHRequest

```
//in API.m
-(SHRequest*)userInfo{

    FROAuthRequest *request = [[FROAuthRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SH_URL_API,SH_URL_USER_INFO]] 
                                                    consumer:consumer 
                                                       token:token 
                                                       realm:nil 
                                           signatureProvider:signatureProvider];

    //wrap the FROAuthRequest in our custom object
    //see below for the SHRequest 
    SHRequest *shRequest = [[SHRequest alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    //set the parsing block
    shRequest.parsingBlock = ^id(FROAuthRequest* finishedRequest){

        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [finishedRequest.responseData objectFromJSONData];

        [user release];
        user = [[SHUser alloc]initWithJSON:[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"user"]];

        //more code

        return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:user,kUserKey,nil];
   };

   [request release];
   return [shRequest autorelease];
}
```

3: The SHRequest

```
//in SHRequest.m
-(id)initWithRequest:(FROAuthRequest*)_underlyingRequest{
    if(self = [super init]){
        underlyingRequest = [_underlyingRequest retain];

        //this is the majority of the post processing
        underlyingRequest.completionBlock = ^{
            //if the requests fails call the fail block
            if(underlyingRequest.responseStatusCode != 200){
                if(failBlock != nil)
                    failBlock();
                return;
            }

            if([underlyingRequest.responseData length] > 0){
                [object release];
                object = parsingBlock(underlyingRequest);
                [object retain];

                if((underlyingRequest.error || !object) && failBlock != nil)
                    failBlock();
                else if(finishBlock != nil)
                    finishBlock();
            }else if(failBlock != nil)
                failBlock();
        };

        underlyingRequest.failedBlock = ^{
            if(failBlock)
                failBlock();
        };
    }
return self;
}
```

4: Once the SHRequest is returned from the userInfo method (1) the finish and fail blocks are set. (For this instance no failBlock is set.

```
//in MainViewController.m
request.finishBlock = ^{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = request.object;

    //User
    SHUser *user = [userInfo objectForKey:kUserKey];

    //more code

};
[request send];
```

**Here's what I have tried**
I moved the completionBlock code to a method that starts the request and used __block types and the leaks appear to have disappeared but some of the __block vars are zombies when the completion block runs.

```
//in SHRequest.m
-(void)send{

    __block void(^fail)(void) = failBlock;
    __block void(^finish)(id) = finishBlock;
    __block id(^parsing)(FROAuthRequest*) = parsingBlock;
    __block FROAuthRequest *req = underlyingRequest;

    underlyingRequest.completionBlock = ^{

        if(req.responseStatusCode != 200){
            if(fail != nil)
                fail();
            return;
        }
        if([req.responseData length] > 0){
           id obj = parsing(req);//<--- parsing is a zombie 

            if((req.error || !obj) && fail != nil)
                fail();
            else if(finish != nil)
                finish(obj);//<--- finish is a zombie
        }else if(fail != nil)
            fail();
    };

    underlyingRequest.failedBlock = ^{
         if(fail)
             fail();
    };

    [underlyingRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post how `failBlock`, `finishBlock`, and `parsingBlock` are declared? Also, is this ARC?

Comment: No its not ARC, and the finish and parsing blocks are already there in the question see point 2 for the parsing and point 4 for the finish.

Comment: So it sounds like the blocks are being released before they're accessed. Are you using the `copy` ownership modifier on the properties? The declaration should look like `@property(copy)id(^parsingBlock)(FROAuthRequest* finishedRequest);`

Comment: Yep, its being copied, there is an autorelease happening just before the blocks execute, due the SHRequest object being returned as an autoreleased object from a method, but I don't understand how that could even be the cause...

Comment: OK, one more question--are you supporting iOS 4, or just 5+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the parsing/finish/fail blocks and passing the request object as a param for the block seems to have sorted out my problem

```
-(void)send{

__block void(^fail)(void) = [failBlock copy];
__block void(^finish)(id) = [finishBlock copy];
__block id(^parsing)(FROAuthRequest*) = [parsingBlock copy];
__block FROAuthRequest *req = underlyingRequest;

underlyingRequest.completionBlock = ^{

    if(req.responseStatusCode != 200){
        if(fail != nil)
            fail();
        return;
    }
    if([req.responseData length] > 0){
       id obj = parsing(req);

        if((req.error || !obj) && fail != nil)
            fail();
        else if(finish != nil)
            finish(obj);
    }else if(fail != nil)
        fail();
};

underlyingRequest.failedBlock = ^{
     if(fail)
         fail();
};

[underlyingRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

and in any request where I need a reference to an ivar or the request itself I create a block var and retain it then release it inside the finish/fail blocks

```
__block SHRequest *req = [request retain];
request.finishBlock = ^(id object){

    NSDictionary *userInfo = object;

    //User
    SHUser *user = [userInfo objectForKey:kUserKey];

    //more code
    [req release];
};

request.failBlock = ^{
    if(req.requestStatusCode == 500)
        //do stuff
    [req release];
};
```

This way Instruments reports no more leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I was thrilled by blocks when they appeared and wrote almost every interface with them. After I while I realized the problems with memory management and readability, which made me return to delegation unless the API *really* calls for blocks. Maybe that would also make your code look better, if that’s not too much code to change.

Comment: I have considered this but its going to require a massive refactoring of code. The request in the question is just one of many, each requiring different code in the parsing blocks. Essentially the SHRequest class is at the core of the app, every request to the server goes through it. If that's the only solution I'll do it but this code is already live on the market so I hope someone can offer a solution that doesn't require time consuming refactoring.

Comment: Blocks are just objects with some syntactic sugar and the memory management is no different from before. You can do exactly the same things as before with delegates with blocks. The only difference is that delegates are usually held by weak references; if you want to do the same thing with blocks, you will need to hold a weak reference to `self`, with `__block` or `__weak`.

Comment: Blocks aren’t just objects because they capture their environment. (I don’t think you can do that in “plain” Objective-C.) That’s why I say that memory management with blocks is a bit different – it’s very easy to create an API that will make you deal with retain cycles all the time (like in this case). Some of the cycles will eventually break automatically, others you have to break by hand, like with the weak `self` aliasing. That’s often clumsy, and that’s why I say that I prefer delegation, because delegation will often give you cleaner code and easier memory management (= API win).

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are reworking the codebase, I'd suggest taking the opportunity to move to ARC.  It will make life MUCH easier in regard to blocks.

If you are going to have to sift through all the code anyway, it may well be worth it... and the ARC automation conversion tools are pretty good.

Even then, though, you will see retain cycles, but ARC plus __weak is a good way to break retain cycles.

Barring that, you are going to have to deal with each block construct individually, not just in the outer method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, then either the `SHRequest` object is gone by the time the completion block runs, or (perhaps less likely) some code has prematurely cleared out your completion block properties. If you were targeting iOS 5, you could solve it by making the block variables weak references, so they wouldn't be invoked if the `SHRequest` object's lifecycle ends before the callback:

```
__weak void(^fail)(void) = failBlock;
```

Since you have to target iOS4, I think the best option is to move the callbacks into methods instead of properties. In this case, the retain cycle still exists, but it's narrowly scoped to the execution of the `underlyingRequest`. Once it executes and releases `completionBlock` and `failedBlock`, the SHRequest can be deallocated (once nothing else is holding onto it). The common problem with block properties is that self retains the block, which retains self, and the only way to break the cycle is to either use a weak reference to self in the block, or explicitly nil out the properties at some point, which can be hard to do in a callback scenario. Here's roughly what your code would look like with methods returning the callback blocks:

```
-(void (^)(void))requestFinishedCallback {
    return [^{
        NSDictionary *userInfo = self.object;

        //User
        SHUser *user = [userInfo objectForKey:kUserKey];

        //more code
    } copy] autorelease];
}

-(void)send{
    underlyingRequest.completionBlock = ^{
        if(req.responseStatusCode != 200){
            [self requestFailedCallback]();
            return;
        }
        if([req.responseData length] > 0){
            id obj = [self parsingBlock](underlyingRequest);

            if (req.error || !obj) {
                [self requestFailedCallback]();
            }
            else {
                [self requestFinishedCallback]();
            }
        } else {
                [self requestFailedCallback]();
        }
    };

    underlyingRequest.failedBlock = [self requestFailedCallback];

    [underlyingRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Incidentally, there are [some other good reasons for returning callback blocks from methods](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/05/block-initialization-for-testability-and-reuse/).